# How to add a Data set to Firestore using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating a signup PHP file that adds a new user to the Firebase-Firestore database. Basically, After I create a user account it should add to Firebase-Firestore collection which is named "users" then it would create a new document that is generated automatically using the firebase autoID feature.

My problem is that my current code does nothing, it has no errors, it just does nothing.

**Here is the code for the submit named: signUp.php**
(it passes it to another php file **(named: signUpAction.php)** that actually does the action of putting it into firestore):

```
<input id="submitme" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" style="float:right" value="CREATE ACCOUNT " />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clicked() {
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to create this account?')) {
            create.submit();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**Here is the whole .PHP file that does the action (Due to the lack of video tutorials this is my understanding of how it should work):**

```
<?php session_start();?>

<?php
    require_once("../diabeatis/vendor/autoload.php");

    // namespace Google\Cloud\Samples\Firestore;

    use Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient;
    function add_doc_data_with_auto_id($projectId){

        $db = new FirestoreClient([
            'assumethatthereisanIDhere' => $projectId,
        ]);

        $data = [
            'allergies' => ($_POST['allergies']),
            'birthDate' => $_POST['birthDate'],
            'diabetesComplication' => ($_POST["diabetesComplication"]),
            'diabetesType' => ($_POST['diabetesType']),
            'firstName' => ($_POST['firstName']),
            'height' => ($_POST['height']),
            'lastName' => ($_POST['lastName']),
            'sex' => ($_POST['sex']),
            'weight' => ($_POST['weight'])
        ];
        $addedDocRef = $db->collection('users')->add($data);
        printf('Added document with ID: %s' . PHP_EOL, $addedDocRef->id());

        echo ("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
        window.alert('The account has been successfully created.');
        window.location.href='../sys/signUp.php';
        </script>");
            exit;
    }

    header("Location: "."../sys/signUp.php");

?>
```

I'm Really in the dark because I'm still figuring out how to develop with PHP and Firestore. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _"Does nothing"_ is a bit of an unspecific and broad error description. Have you done any debugging? Checked how the request comes in and goes through the flow? Checked what the variables contain in different scenarios etc? Checked the servers error log?

Comment: Also, you seem to have an empty line between the code blocks (starting the session and crating the function) while ending on a redirect. Headers must go _before_ any output (including empty lines).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson after running it in my browser, it just refreshes as if it successfully added to the Firestore but upon checking in the console, nothing happened. I checked the IDE for problems it reported no problems whatsoever.

Comment: You also never use that function, nor can it be used  anywhere else (since you redirect the user right after the function is declared). A function must be called at some point for it to actually do anything.

Answer (score 0):

are you using this `$addedDocRef = $db->collection('users')->add($data);` change `add` to `create($data)` work fine me this changing.

and also Change this line `$addedDocRef = $db->collection('users')->add($data);` to this `$addedDocRef = $db->collection('users')->document(your document name)->create($data);`